# What's the reason for the pre-image def. of Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

What's the reason for the pre-image def. of Lebesgue measurable?

I.e. $f$ Lebesgue measurable if $\{ x : f(x) > c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is measurable.

Like why is it significant that $f(x) > c$?

Comment: An equivalent intuitive characterization is that measurable functions are the ones that can be approximated by simple functions.

Comment: The gist here is that it implies immediately that we can measure $f$ on intervals which is the key idea for Lebesgue integrals.